# What happened to .dev TLD?

Tags: google, top-level-domains

What happened to the `.dev` TLD?

The official planned release was at the begin of may, but there was no release and I couldn't find anything new about it since then.

Actually I wanted to buy one, has anyone got informations about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The official release date will be the **28.02.2019**, so it seems like the information from the icannwiki are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing "happened" to the `.DEV` TLD. It is owned by Google, who decides on its own what it does with it.

There are no official communication about it for now. It is still expected to go online, after the `.APP` one last may.

You will certainly hear about it all over the news when Google moves. They dig their `.APP` start almost at the same time as some Google I/O conference in may.

If you go to https://www.registry.google/ you will see that they currently plan to go forward with `.page` instead, this october.

When (Before) they start, they are mandated to give ICANN some information on dates, as a sunrise period is mandatory. These details will appear then here: https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods/dev
It is empty for now, but you can compare with the page(!) on `.PAGE` at https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods/page

So you can not buy one currently, and you should stay away from any "pre-reservation" offers, especially so far in advance where dates are even not known.

Note that `.DEV` will run like `.APP` technically as they are both in the HSTS Preloading list: you will need an X.509 certificate to have your website work on `.DEV`.

Comment: Launch details published: https://www.registry.google/announcements/launch-details-for-dev/